# how to collect many tuple from a list in python in one line?

Tags: python, list

for example:

If I want to make a array b from a like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [i for i in a]
```

then b will be `[1, 2, 3]`

now, I want to make a tuple list like this:
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)] from a

how to write this in one line?

I know how to write this function like this:

```
b = []
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        if i == j: continue
        b.append((i, j))
```

but I wonder how to write this function in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(permutations(a, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3]
>>>b = [(n,m) for n in a for m in a if n!=m]
>>>
>>>print b
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: It's called list comprehension. As to *why* it works - well, it is a for loop and if inside a list constructor for convenience. Btw, is the lack of this explanation why I haven't received any upvotes but the other answer did? Sigh.

Comment: Yes that will be the reason - the point to realise is that if you understand list comprehensions you probably would not ask the question in the first place